# Error in data view when connecting to an Oracle DB

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

When using SharePoint Designer I found this link that stepped me through how to get it working:

http://spsolution.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-insert-data-source-in-sharepoint.html

That allowed SharePoint Designer to talk to Oracle, but when I placed a data view on a page it gave me the following error:

```
Error while executing web part: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: 
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected      
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)     
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)     
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals)     
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.Syst...       

09/14/2009 14:40:23.52* w3wp.exe (0x0FA0)                               
0x1A88 Windows SharePoint Services   Web Parts                                 
89a1     Monitorable       ...
em.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)     
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)     
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments)     
at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal() ...       

09/14/2009 14:40:23.52* w3wp.exe (0x0FA0)                               
0x1A88 Windows SharePoint Services   Web Parts                                 
89a1     Monitorable       ...    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator(IDataSource datasource, Boolean originalData)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform()
```

I am mystified.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting an error when the SQL command is executed against the database. (OracleCommand.Execute) is the eror line. The error says that it does not expect the "from" statement in your "select * from" I would suspect there is some extra string data in the command string being passed.

Comment: The select is properly formatted as it works just fine through SharePoint Designer and via an Oracle client as well

Comment: Are you getting anything in the Oracle logs?